# How to run multiple maven project using Maven Jetty Plug-in in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

So, what I want to do is to run multiple maven web project in eclipse using Jetty. Let say I have two projects webProjectOne and webProjectTwo. I run Jetty using follow setting[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcZBo.png).

However, this can only run one project at a time. Is there a way to run multiple project at once?

For Example:

```
localhost:8080/webProjectOne
localhost:8080/webProjectTwo
```

[image: Debug project using Jetty in eclipse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run 2 web-app in the same port (`8080`)

```
localhost:8080/webProjectOne
localhost:8080/webProjectTwo
```

If you setting 2 projects has own port, you release 2 `mvn jetty:run` commands at 2 different directory/folder.

Read more at https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think I will just run one project in jetty server setting the port with 8080 and another one with Tomcat setting the port to 8081 for debug purpose. Thanks